# Image download from canvas doesn't work in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, download, internet-explorer-11

I have a seadragon canvas that displays a deep zoom image.

```
viewer.addHandler('open', function() {                  
    var downloadlink = document.getElementById("download");
    $(downloadlink).on("click", function() {
        var img = viewer.drawer.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        if (document.getElementById("as-original").checked) {
            AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: '@Model.AccessId', secretAccessKey: '@Model.AccessKey'});
            AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
            var s3 = new AWS.S3();
            var params = {Bucket: '@Model.OriginalsBucket', Key: '@Model.OriginalsKey'};
            s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function (err, urlS3) {
                img = urlS3;
            });
        }
        downloadlink.href = img;
        alert(img);
        downloadlink.download = '@Model.DatabaseName';
        alert(downloadlink.download);            
    });
});
```

The download button works in all browsers except for IE 11. There are two download options, to download the image as it currently appears on the canvas (zoomed in and positioned as desired), or to download the original file. Both work the same on all other browsers, but in IE,

(1) With "as-original" NOT checked, nothing happens. Both alerts go off, so I can see that there's nothing breaking in the code... it just doesn't do anything once the code is done. I added

```
 window.location.href = img;
```

to the end but it still doesn't do anything.

(2) With "as-original" checked, after downloadlink.download, a new page loads that shows the image, but nothing downloads, the page doesn't show any download or print options/dialog, nothing. Just a static image on an otherwise blank page.

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer does not *currently* support the `download` attribute, though it is presently listed as *under consideration* on [http://status.modern.ie](https://status.modern.ie/adownloadattribute?term=download). Additionally, you cannot use dataURIs as navigable content to prevent [certain phishing techniques](http://klevjers.com/papers/phishing.pdf) that leverage dataURIs.

If you want to download a file onto the user's machine you should instead use the appropriate API for that: [`navigator.msSaveBlob`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772332(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution that works. You need canvas-toBlob.js and FileSaver.js. This method is able to open/save image on IE without opening any new tabs, and also does not run into any tainted canvas issues (since many of my images are from other origins).

```
$(downloadlink).on("click", function() {
    var img = viewer.drawer.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    if (document.getElementById("as-original").checked)
        img = url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + '$dist';


    // detect browser
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) { // If Internet Explorer, return version number
        $(".line-bg").append("<img style='display:none' id='myImage' src='" + img + "' alt='from canvas'/><canvas id='myCanvas' width='1138' height='598' style='display:none;border:1px solid #cccccc'></canvas>");
        var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
        var imgDupe = document.getElementById('myImage');
        ctx.drawImage(imgDupe, 10, 10);
        c.toBlob(function(blob) {
            saveAs(blob, '@Model.DatabaseName' + '.jpg');
        });
        } else {
            downloadlink.href = img;
            downloadlink.download = '@Model.DatabaseName';
    }
});
```

I go through the steps of creating a new image and canvas for several reasons: (1) I'm trying to download the image as it currently appears on my seadragon canvas, i.e. zoomed in/positioned as desired. Therefore I grab canvas.toDataUrl(), and display that in a new canvas which gets transformed into a blob. (2) I have cross-origin images on my canvas, so the new image/canvas process gets around any potential tainted canvas issues.

If you're not using seadragon and just have a regular canvas, you can probably replace everything before c.toBlob() with var c = document.getElementById('[original canvas]'). You probably don't need to go through creating a new image and new canvas and can just transform the original canvas directly into a blob. I'm not sure if it will work if you have a CORS image on your canvas though.

Anyway, this method should work for any canvas downloading in IE, and if you're not using seadragon you can probably cut out a bunch of the steps I used.

Comment: I can almost guarantee that this approach is going to break as it relies on the user-agent string being immutable. Not only does Internet Explorer no longer have a sub-string of MSIE, the Trident version number is also prone to change. What problem did you have with the method I provided [in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27493569/54680)?